# ipv6 not public availible

Tags: networking, dns, apache-http-server, ipv6

I'm trying to get my server to be public availible on IPV6
I did the test on: http://test-ipv6.com and it's 10/10

I've set my primary and secundairy servers to Google's (on the server)
when I connect to the Ipv4 address it works just fine

I am using wamp as server, and I copied my vhost config for local testing and change the ServerName to the public one.

Is it possible that 2x the same Vhost is added with Only a different ServerName?

Firewall is completly off.
and forward rule is set as following:
[image]

I went to IPv6 test http://ipv6-test.com/ and that gave me the following :
[image]

nslookup values:

```
<mydomain>      is the domain I own
<currentDomain> is the domain where I did the nslookup from
<ipv6>          is the ip of my computer
<localServer>   is the local server in the company
```

lookup

```
> sitename.<mydomain>
Server:  <localServer>
Address:  <ip>

------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 2, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        sitename.<mydomain>.<currentDomain>, type = A, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  <currentDomain>
        ttl = 1200 (20 mins)
        primary name server = <localServer>
        responsible mail addr = administrator.<currentDomain>
        serial  = 3659580
        refresh = 3600 (1 hour)
        retry   = 600 (10 mins)
        expire  = 259200 (3 days)
        default TTL = 1200 (20 mins)

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 3, rcode = NXDOMAIN
        header flags:  response, auth. answer, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        sitename.<mydomain>.<currentDomain>, type = AAAA, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  <currentDomain>
        ttl = 1200 (20 mins)
        primary name server = <localServer>
        responsible mail addr = administrator.<currentDomain>
        serial  = 3659580
        refresh = 3600 (1 hour)
        retry   = 600 (10 mins)
        expire  = 259200 (3 days)
        default TTL = 1200 (20 mins)

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 4, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 0,  authority records = 1,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        sitename.<mydomain>, type = A, class = IN
    AUTHORITY RECORDS:
    ->  <mydomain>
        ttl = 3423 (57 mins 3 secs)
        primary name server = ns1.nomeo.be
        responsible mail addr = hostmaster.<mydomain>
        serial  = 2015040806
        refresh = 7200 (2 hours)
        retry   = 7200 (2 hours)
        expire  = 604800 (7 days)
        default TTL = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
------------
Got answer:
    HEADER:
        opcode = QUERY, id = 5, rcode = NOERROR
        header flags:  response, want recursion, recursion avail.
        questions = 1,  answers = 1,  authority records = 0,  additional = 0

    QUESTIONS:
        sitename.<mydomain>, type = AAAA, class = IN
    ANSWERS:
    ->  sitename.<mydomain>
        AAAA IPv6 address = <ipv6>
        ttl = 3600 (1 hour)

------------
Name:    sitename.<mydomain>
Address:  <ipv6>
```

Comment: `I've set my primary and secundary servers to Google's` I read this as "I have set my DNS resolver to look up DNS queries via one of Googles servers". Which can be nice. But where did you configure your own nameservers. Not the lookup part, but the part where your DNS server answers queries.

Comment: not completly sure what you mean but for the question I think you are asking: i've set my AAAA record to the ipv6 ip in my domainnameprovider admin panel

Answer (score 3):

The authoritative DNS servers for your domain name are not reachable over IPv6. You should talk to your domainname-provider and ask them to make the DNS servers available over IPv6.

Comment: I concur. If there is a locally administered authoritative DNS, adding the IPv6 records there should fix this.